# OpenCV color extraction in iOS

Tags: ios, image, opencv, image-processing, extract

I have a `CvVideoCamera` and I'm trying to detect the blue color in each frame, and the output frames should contain only the blue objects, like [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html). I'm doing this in the delegate method:

```
- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image
{
    cv::Mat bgrMat;
    cvtColor(image, bgrMat, CV_BGRA2BGR);

    // Covert color space to HSV
    cv::Mat hsvMat;
    cvtColor(bgrMat, hsvMat, CV_BGR2HSV);

    // Threshold the HSV image
    cv::Mat blueMask;

    cv::Scalar lower_blue(110, 50, 50);
    cv::Scalar upper_blue(130, 255, 255);

    cv::inRange(hsvMat, lower_blue, upper_blue, blueMask);
    bitwise_and(bgrMat, bgrMat, image, blueMask);
}
```

Original image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

The blue color detection seems to be working fine, but the final result is red instead of blue. Any ideas why? Am I using the `bitwise_and` correctly?

**[Edit]**

These lines do the trick:

```
    cv::Mat output;
    image.copyTo(output, blueMask);
    output.copyTo(image);
```

instead of:

```
    bitwise_and(bgrMat, bgrMat, image, blueMask);
```

Thanks to [karlphillip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176769/karlphillip) for the suggestion. For some reason the `bgrMat` gets 'altered' along the way, so I'm using the original `image` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to accomplish is to copy the pixels from the input image using a blue mask, right? Adjust your code at the end to:

```
cv::inRange(hsvMat, lower_blue, upper_blue, blueMask);

cv::Mat output;
bgrMat.copyTo(output, blueMask);
```

Comment: Tried already, same result: red instead of blue. But thanks for the fast answer. (note: the output is the 'image' parameter)

Comment: Display `blueMask` on the screen and see if it makes sense. You might have switched some values on `cv::Scalar` (Remember, they are still in the BGR order, **not** RGB).

Comment: The blueMask is white in the blue area and black in rest. For the blue range scalars I'm using the values from **[this](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html)** tutorial.